# Is there any way to get a bigger swipe area for a drawer layout to open?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I created this left drawer on my app in Android studio, but I have to swipe all the way from the left of my screen for it to show up, i wanted to swipe left from the center of the screen, how can I do that?

Comment: short answer - no. Long answer - Google have their own UI design criteria, thus it's a good idea to stick to them. You can check this question here for more information https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16583395/touch-anywhere-to-slide-open-menu-for-navigation-drawer

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.